# is there a way to detect 404 using grunt/node?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I've got a .html page with several links on it, I want to check the links through grunt and fail the build if I get a 404 or similar status basically anything but a 200

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an inadvisable testing strategy. Either those links point to pages that you own - in which case you should test thems directly; or they point to pages outside of your control, and there's nothing you can do about their response status anyway.

If you *really* want to do something like this, you could write a script that finds all links on a page eg `$('a')`, makes an ajax request to them and verifies the status code.